# Linking Stacktrace from Glassfish log output to source code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console, glassfish, logging

I'm running an application in a **Glassfish** server from **Eclipse** using verbose output. Therefore, all the logging gets written into the console. The thing is that when an exception occurs, I can see the **stacktrace in the console**, but it's **not linked to the source code**. ¿Is there any way I can have it linked so I don't have to look for it by hand?